# Indices issue in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, indices

I have a problem that I know is very small but it's wrecking my head because I can't see where the error is coming from! The code that I'm working with (in Octave) is:

```
      g = 9.814;
      Mend = 128;

      U = 15.0;

      wm = g/U;
      dw = 0.05;
      Hs = 0.16*(U*U)/g;

      sum = 0.0;
      for j = 1:Mend
      w(j) = dw + (2*j-1)*dw/2.0;
      Gw(j) = (5.0/16.0)*(wm^4/(w(j)^5))*(Hs^2)(exp(-1.25*(wm^4/(w(j)^4))));
      sum = sum + Gw(j);
      end

      plot(w,Gw);
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
 subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

In relation to the line:

```
Gw(j) = (5.0/16.0)*(wm^4/(w(j)^5))*(Hs^2)(exp(-1.25*(wm^4/(w(j)^4))));
```

I'm going crazy because I can't see which subscript indices thinks its zero!

Really appreciate any help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! I just realised I was missing a * between the Hs and the exp in that equation.. Very silly mistake!